# jQuery Autocomplete - Is caching no longer an option?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Using jQuery Autocomplete, according to the docs you have to do the following to cache:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var cache = {},
        lastXhr;
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var term = request.term;
            if ( term in cache ) {
                response( cache[ term ] );
                return;
            }

            lastXhr = $.getJSON( "search.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                cache[ term ] = data;
                if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Didn't there used to be an option to cache? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Caching for [*jQueryUI autocomplete*](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete) was never an option.

There *was* a `cacheLength` option for *jQuery autocomplete* (Jörn Zaefferer's now deprecated autocomplete plugin).

In the [migration guide](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide) from autocomplete --> jQueryUI autocomplete, Jörn mentions this:

> **cacheLength:** There is no built-in caching support anymore, but it's really easy to implement your own, as shown by the [Remote with caching demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache).

If you are using the caching implementation frequently, you could wrap the functionality in another plugin that encapsulates it.